# Get IP addresses currently using designated port number

Tags: vb.net, tcp, ip, port

I have a simple TCP client-server setup made in vb.net. I would like to know if it is possible to return all the IP addresses currently using the designated port number, and how would I go about it?

Comment: See [How can I get all the the active TCP connections using .NET Framework (no unmanaged PE import!)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806435/how-can-i-get-all-the-the-active-tcp-connections-using-net-framework-no-unmana).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the VB.NET solution translated from [IPGlobal​Properties.​Get​Active​Tcp​Connections   Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_NetworkInformation_IPGlobalProperties_GetActiveTcpConnections).

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ShowActiveTcpConnections()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowActiveTcpConnections()
        Debug.WriteLine("Active TCP Connections")
        Dim properties As IPGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties
        Dim connections() As TcpConnectionInformation = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections
        For Each c As TcpConnectionInformation In connections
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}", c.LocalEndPoint.ToString, c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Example of output:

```
Active TCP Connections
127.0.0.1:1028 <==> 127.0.0.1:5354
127.0.0.1:1029 <==> 127.0.0.1:5354
127.0.0.1:1055 <==> 127.0.0.1:27015
127.0.0.1:1069 <==> 127.0.0.1:27015
127.0.0.1:1071 <==> 127.0.0.1:27015
127.0.0.1:1080 <==> 127.0.0.1:27015
127.0.0.1:1081 <==> 127.0.0.1:5354
127.0.0.1:1082 <==> 127.0.0.1:5354
127.0.0.1:1084 <==> 127.0.0.1:1085
127.0.0.1:1085 <==> 127.0.0.1:1084
127.0.0.1:1154 <==> 127.0.0.1:27015
127.0.0.1:5354 <==> 127.0.0.1:1028
```